# Could somebody give me a physical description of what each button/connector does on the Game Boy Advance SP?

Tags: game-boy-advance

I've just discovered that I still (somehow) have my Game Boy Advance SP console from back in the day. I'm totally blind, and whilst I used to spend hundreds of happy hours playing games when I first got the console I can't recall what the buttons/inputs do. Would somebody be able to give a breakdown of each button/connector so that I can have a proper play around?

In other words: all I need is the physical description of what's printed on the button/port.

Comment: What do you mean by a "physical description"? I can only tell you what the in-game result of pressing a button does

Comment: Given that the OP is blind, I think they are asking for an explanation of what the different buttons correspond to, such as "on the right, there are two buttons, the left one is B and the right one is A" and so on.

Comment: This - this is exactly the kind of thing that I'm looking for. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK .. I'll try to describe it.

Let's say you are holding the console opened with your hands ready to press the buttons.

On the left, there is the Control Pad.

Up right of the pad, there is a small button, that's the On/off Switch for the screen.

Straight right from the control pad, there are the B button, then the A (a little bit higher).

Down in the middle, there are the Select (left) and Start (right) button.

They are just under the speaker, so you should have an easy time to feel/spot them.

On the two sides, behind the hinges, it's the L and R shoulder buttons (L for left shoulder, R for the right shoulder).

Finally, there are two switches on the side of the console.

On the left side, away from the cartidge slot (around where your left index might be resting), there is the volume sliding switch. "Loud" is up/away from you.

On the right side, near the cartridge slot (where you right hand palm is) there is the on/off switch for the console. "On" is up/away from you.

Comment: To add to that, you should check a game called Soundvoyager.
It's a game that plays heavily with the sounds. More info [here](https://nintendo.fandom.com/wiki/Bit_Generations:_Soundvoyager)

Comment: Really useful info - thank you. I've actually already tried the mentioned game and love it, but thank you for the recommendation! :) Just out of interest - on my console, directly below the screen I have a small button. What's this one used for?

Comment: That's the screen light button, the one that makes the console playable in the dark.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. :) One more question if that's ok - are both of the connectors at the back the same, or do these have different uses?

Comment: They actually have different uses. Let's say you are holding the SP the same way as previously.
The left one would be the link cable / Gamecube cable connector.
The right one is the AC adaptor connector.
There is a small difference in the shapes (the AC adaptor connector is more squarey).

Comment: Thank you. :) One last question if that's ok - with the AC adaptor connector, is this also the same one that can be used to connect a pair of headphones? I must have done this at some point but can't remember!

Comment: Yes exactly. I've never done it myself but that's what the manual says.